# Bulk Download PDFs from Google Scholar

Tags: publications, website, tools, google-scholar

I would like to download ~100 scholarly articles from Google Scholar. I have institutional access, so Google Scholar presents the available PDF. Is there a way to automate the downloading of the PDF files?

Comment: why would one need an institutional access to GS? it's just open

Comment: @Ilya I guess the OP meant he has access to the articles that are behind pay walls. To the OP: please confirm this.

Comment: Exactly. I can download the PDFs directly from a link on the Google Scholar page, without paying

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has to do with the mechanics of downloading articles, and not with academia.

Comment: You might want to check your university's policies. Some forbid automated downloading/crawling and may result in a permanent ban from using the institutional access.

Comment: @BobBrown - If you feel it's off topic, which StackExchange community would you suggest I post to?

Comment: Additionally, check Google Scholar's ToS. They may also prohibit automated access or scraping.

Answer (score 6):

I know one relatively simple way.
**[Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) + a [Google Scholar Zotero](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zotero-scholar-citations/) plugin for you browser (typically, Firefox or Chrome).**
Bibliographic manager. The program helps you to download bibliographic meta-data together with the PDFs (if they are open).
So, you may "save" all the needed papers to "My library" in GS (if you have several collections, you may assign a special "label" to each collection). Then, when you have all the papers in one list, just export them all to Zotero. Whenever possible, Zotero will download a PDF.